# How to configure my 404 response

Tags: php

How would I be able to correctly redirect a person who visits my site to my 404 page? I have already created my 404.php file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page not found | Twilight of Spirits</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://forum.umbradora.net/template/default/css/404.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<div id="error">
  <a href="http://forum.umbradora.net/">
    <img src="/forum/template/default/images/layout/404.png" alt="404 page not found"   id="error404-image">
  </a>
</div>


<div id="mixpanel" style="visibility: hidden; "></div></body></html>
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://forum.umbradora.net/404.php
```

Now when I go to my site and enter a false link such as mack.php or total.html, I get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>     The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete  your request.
>     Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@umbradora.net and inform them of the   time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>     More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>     Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument  to handle the request.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have tried switching from subdomain to my normal path, still get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it solve your problem but you should set the 404 header on top of your site.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
.....
?>
```

Perhaps you have an error on your site. Check the apache error log to get some more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534268/headerhttp-1-0-404-not-found-not-doing-anything

Comment: I have tried your method, aswell as icktoofay's. I still get the same error. I also moved the two from forum and put them inside my root. Changed the paths in both files, and its still an error. Its a possibility that its my hosts settings. I will look into it thanks.

Comment: look at the post from @moonwave99 this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a local path, e.g. `ErrorDocument 404 404.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the 404 document may not point to a full URL, only to a relative path.